# Best practice for threaded getter method

Tags: android, android-asynctask, getter

I also faced with the NetworkOnMainThreadException in my application but I don't see how to resolve it.
I have a class with a getter method. Like:

```
public ArrayList<News> get(int i){
   // get the list of news from a HTML on the net. The news are split up into web pages   on the site
   // and i is the page number
   return NewsParser(i);
}
```

Since Android throws the exception I come up with an idea of a downloader class which downloads the HTML content in a separate thread

```
pubic ArrayList<News> get(int i){
   Downloader dl = new Downloader(i);
   String HTMLcontent = dl.getContent(); <-- AsyncTask starts in getContent()
   return NewsParser(HTMLcontent); <-- What happens here in the main thread???
}
```

Any ideas/best practices for this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Just looking at your code and your question, it seems like you don't have a very solid understanding of how AsyncTask (or threads in general) works.

I would recommend reading [this article](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidBackgroundProcessing/article.html).

Basically, your AsyncTask should query the web URL and download the data.  Once the data is complete, your AsyncTask should send the HTMLContent to a handler object.  The handler will be running on your main thread, so you can display the information to the user at that point.

You shouldn't be calling

```
dl.getContent();
```

to retrieve the content.  AsyncTask runs on a separate thread, so you can't just call methods like this from your main thread.  You need to create the Downloader object (like you did) and then call

```
dl.execute();
```

to start the AsyncTask.

Comment: Yeah, thanks. I already read this, but still don't understand what is a Handler. :(

Answer (score 0):

run the get method inside a thread,

```
    new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // call get method here

        }

    }).start();
```

Comment: Yes, but I still don't see what the hell should happen in the main thread while the html is being downloaded. And what should happen if the page is downloaded.

Comment: explain what your are trying to do exactly, showing a progress bar?

Comment: I don't want to do anything:) Android forces me to do something :)

Answer (score 0):

Since Honeycomb (Android 3.0) you can't use Networking Operations in the MainThread to avoid freezes on the Phone. This is important in order to make your app responsive.

More info:

[NetworkOnMainThreadException](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/NetworkOnMainThreadException.html)

[Responsiveness](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/design/responsiveness.html)